# JavaFX pie chart not showing

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, pie-chart, scenebuilder

So I have this JavaFX application and I create 4 pie charts with SceneBuilder and add them to the scene. Then I query my database to get some data and I set it to the pie charts in the method below. However, something very strange happens. If I am looking at the current scene when the update happens it all works fine. If I am looking at a different scene, the pie charts don't show. Please help. The get methods don't involve any calculations if that matters.

fields:

```
@FXML
    private PieChart pieGender;
    @FXML
    private PieChart pieAge;
    @FXML
    private PieChart pieIncome;
    @FXML
    private PieChart pieContext;
```

update method:

```
//extracts and display data on this panel
    public synchronized void updatePanelData() {
        //update from the fx thread
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            ObservableList<PieChart.Data> gender = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new PieChart.Data("Male", this.dataRetriever.getGenderMale()),
                    new PieChart.Data("Female", this.dataRetriever.getGenderFemale())
            );

            this.pieGender.setData(gender);

            ObservableList<PieChart.Data> age = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new PieChart.Data("<25", this.dataRetriever.getAgeLessThan25()),
                    new PieChart.Data("25-34", this.dataRetriever.getAge25To34()),
                    new PieChart.Data("35-44", this.dataRetriever.getAge35To44()),
                    new PieChart.Data("45-54", this.dataRetriever.getAge45To54()),
                    new PieChart.Data(">54", this.dataRetriever.getAgeOver54())
            );

            this.pieAge.setData(age);

            ObservableList<PieChart.Data> income = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new PieChart.Data("Low", this.dataRetriever.getLowIncome()),
                    new PieChart.Data("Medium", this.dataRetriever.getMedIncome()),
                    new PieChart.Data("High", this.dataRetriever.getHighIncome())
            );

            this.pieIncome.setData(income);

            ObservableList<PieChart.Data> context = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new PieChart.Data("News", this.dataRetriever.getContextNews()),
                    new PieChart.Data("Shopping", this.dataRetriever.getContextShopping()),
                    new PieChart.Data("Social Media", this.dataRetriever.getContextSocialMedia()),
                    new PieChart.Data("Blog", this.dataRetriever.getContextBlog()),
                    new PieChart.Data("Hobbies", this.dataRetriever.getContextHobbies()),
                    new PieChart.Data("Travel", this.dataRetriever.getContextTravel())
            );

            this.pieContext.setData(context);


            this.labelClick.setText(this.dataRetriever.getNumberOfClicks().toString());
            this.labelServer.setText(this.dataRetriever.getServerNumber().toString());
            this.labelImpression.setText(this.dataRetriever.getNumberOfImpressions().toString());

            this.updateDateFilter();
        });
    }
```

What happens if I am not looking at the pie charts' scene while the update happens:
[image]

Comment: Do all pie-charts in the same scene?

Comment: @EmreDalkiran yes they are

Comment: I am trying to understand your problem. When you are in a different scene other than the one containing pie-charts and an update happens, you can not see the pie charts, which are in a different scene. Is that correct?

Comment: @EmreDalkiran yes

Comment: Stages can show only one scene simultaneously, if you want to switch to the pie-chart scene automatically when an update occurs, you should implement it yourself.

Comment: @EmreDalkiran I do not want to switch automatically. I switch to it through a button manually after the update is done and when I do that I can not see the pie charts.

Comment: I got it. Seems more like a threading issue to me. From which thread are you calling `Platform.runLater`?

Comment: @EmreDalkiran from a Task I use to query the database and get the data, after it is done, it calls this method

Comment: When you switch back to pie-chart scene, how do you access to values to draw charts? Can you log the values of charts when you switched back to the pie-chart scene and no chart has been drawn?